# Problems with response snapshot of firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.getCompanies = app.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  const starCountRef = app.database.ref("company/");
  starCountRef.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    res.send(snapshot.val());
  });

});

exports.getCompanies = app.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  const starCountRef = app.database.ref("company/");
  var data;
  starCountRef.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    data = snapshot.val();
  });
  res.send(data);
});
```

These are the two ways im trying to send back a response. The first one just loads so im guessing its stuck in the onCreate. The second one gives me undefined which im guessing i need to wait a bit longer before the data gets the snapshot. But ive tried to add a then to the onCreate but it didnt work since its not a async function.

Before i used functions ive written the restapi locally and then the second method worked to send back the data. But now im getting undefined.

If anyone has a solution for this it would be very appriciated. I need a way to wait for the data. Is it a promise?  How would it be implemented in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to read a Realtime Database node from an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and send back the result. In a Cloud Function for Firebase you need to use the [Node.js Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node) in order to interact with the Firebase services.

The following should do the trick:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.getCompanies = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const starCountRef = admin.database().ref("company/");
        const snapshot = await starCountRef.get()

        res.status(200).send(snapshot.val());
    } catch (error) {
        // Watch the video https://youtu.be/7IkUgCLr5oA
    }
    
});
```

Note that:

- We use `functions.https.onRequest` and not `app.https.onRequest`
- We use `async`/`await` because the `get()` method is asynchronous
- How we import, initialize and use the Admin SDK (`admin.database().ref("company/");`).

Comment: Thank you that did it.

This way seems better than mine and dont have to think about promises.

Comment: Glad I could help you. FYI Promises are still there :-) but async/await is ["a special syntax to work with promises in a more comfortable fashion"](https://javascript.info/async-await)